# Looping through dynamic object: signalData[signals].data is not a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, foreach

Hello I am trying to loop though multiple Objects.

In my solution I try to archive that with the `for(... in ...)` loop:

```js
        var signalData = {
          signal1: {
            name: "signal1",
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
          },
          signal2: {
            name: "signal2",
            data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
          },
          signal3: {
            name: "signal3",
            data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
          },
        }

        var output = [];

        for (var signals in signalData) {
          var dat = Object.keys(signalData[signals].data);

          //console.log(dat);

          dat.forEach((signal) => {
            if (signal >= 3 && signal <= 7) {
              output.push(signalData[signals].data(signal));
            }
          });
        }

console.log(output)
```

`console.log(dat);` gives me back the right data as it should be but in the `forEach` im getting this error in console: `signalData[signals].data is not a function`
I can't figure out what's the problem. Maybe someone has already solved a similar problam and can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with some sample data that produces the error.

Comment: Thank you. I added an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwuhsL9r/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `signal` is a key for the object `signalData[signals].data`. You are calling it as a function with this line

```js
output.push(signalData[signals].data(signal));
```

Instead, try this, in order to access the property on the object.

```js
output.push(signalData[signals].data[signal]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Object.keys`, you can simply use an index-based `for` loop to traverse the array.

```js
var signalData = {
  signal1: {
    name: "signal1",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
  },
  signal2: {
    name: "signal2",
    data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
  },
  signal3: {
    name: "signal3",
    data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
  },
}

var output = [];
for (var signals in signalData) {
  var dat = signalData[signals].data;
  for(let i = 3; i < Math.min(dat.length, 8); i++){
    output.push(dat[i]);
  }
}
console.log(output)
```